# How to do normalization for each feature using Hadoop Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Now, I have a data like this:

```
data_new = 
    foreach data
    generate
        (float)$0,
        (float)$1,
        ......;
```

If `data_new` only `2` columns, I know we can do normalization to each column as following:

```
grp_data = group data_new all;
tmp = foreach grp_data {
    sum0 = SUM($0);
    sum1 = SUM($1);
    count = COUNT(data_new);
    generate
        flatten(data_new),
        sum0/count as mean1,
        sum1/count as mean2,
        count as count;
};

tmp = foreach tmp {
    diff0 = ($0 - mean0) * ($0 - mean0);
    diff1 = ($1 - mean1) * ($1 - mean1);
    geneate *, diff0 as diff0, diff1 as diff1;
};

grp_data = group tmp all;
tmp = 
    foreach grp_data 
    generate
        flatten(tmp),
        SUM(tmp.diff0) as diff0,
        SUM(tmp.diff1) as diff1;

tmp =
    foreach tmp
    generate 
        ($0 - mean0) / (SQRT(diff0/count)),
        ($1 - mean1) / (SQRT(diff1/count));
```

When there are **too many columns** in `data_new`, it is impossible to use the above way. So could I ask if there is any way to realize the same function?

Comment: Write an UDF.Pass the row to the UDF and in the UDF,split the row and foreach column apply the function and concat the result and return.

Comment: @inquisitive_mind Can this be achieved only using Pig build-in functions?

Comment: @inquisitive_mind First I have to compute the mean, then the standard deviation. Since there are too many columns in the feature, I don't know how to compute the mean and the standard deviation. Thank you!